# promised skype interview twice recuiter never called

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, unprofessional-behavior

I'm so pissed! I've been in contact with the hr director of a big company whom promised me twice an interview on Skype but never called. I'm wanting some help on writing an email explaining how disappointed I am and how unprofessional the situation is. To top it off the position I've applied for was for a recruiting position within the company!

Comment: Write that email here and ask for comments. We're not here to do your work. And for starters: stop being pissed, there could be good reasons for the missed appointments. You just don't know what happened and you have only your interpretations.

Comment: That's Great but shouldnt I have received an email with an apology? And possible reschedule? I'm not asking yypou to write the email for me I'm asking for suggestions..

Comment: What was the reason they gave for missing the first one?

Comment: For Skype appts its essential to have a backup number ready in case. Skype is not known by me for reliability

Answer (score 4):

OK, I realise your angry about being stood up but DON'T write that email, you'll just succeed in burning the bridge.

There are a number of reasons why it may not have happened, from the obvious overrunning meetings to maybe as simple as the hr director couldn't use skype (or had your skype name wrong).  Is it worth bombing out a job I'm assuming you were otherwise interested in?

Calm down, then contact them by non-skype means.  Mention there seemed to be a problem at their end as everything was fine from yours (you're sure it was, had you tested calling your skype account?).  Suggest you're still interested and if they'd like to rearrange the interview (maybe by a different format, you can get a 3 person webex account for free and you set up the conference).

You'd be surprised how often in a case like this they were sitting there not getting an answer to their call due to typos and maybe it isn't their fault.

Another thing to remember is that the person will be doing this call in addition to their normal day job (even an HR director), it's possible that something more important came up at short notice (I know your job search is very important to you, but I bet it's just one of the hundred things the interviewer has to deal with especially if they are having  to interview for someone to do their recruitment).

If you don't want to deal with them any more, still take the high road and thank them for their consideration.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I would not be taking initiative to contact the recruiter anymore. Maybe they will reach out to you again, apologize and explain what happened. If you're satisfied with their response, great! You can continue along, hopefully reschedule and move on. If you aren't satisfied with their reason for standing you up for two interviews, then a simple "Thank you for your consideration, but I am no longer interested in this position." will do. That should get the point across while being professional. Frankly, I wouldn't be mad that they never called - I would be glad that I learned how they operate before I signed on to work with them.

Comment: Yeah, but given the job is to fill where they are falling down, it seems it's more of an opportunity, the OP can see where they are struggling and use it to both get the job and shine in the role.